# How do I display all comments from an API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api

```
function News() {
const[stories, setStories] = useState([]);


useEffect(() => {

    const getStoriesData = async () => {
        await fetch("https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?tags=(story,poll)")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {

            const stories = data.hits.map(({title,url,points,children}) => ({title,url,points,children}))
            console.log(stories)

            setStories(stories);
        });
    }

    getStoriesData();
}, []);


return(
    <div className="news">
        <table className = "table">
            <tr ><th>Title</th> <th>Points</th></tr>
            {stories.map((story) => (            
                <tr>
                    <td><a className="title" href={story.url}>{story.title}</a></td>
                    <td><div className="points">{story.points}</div></td>
                    <td><div className="comments">{story.children.length}</div></td>
                </tr>               
            ))}
        </table>
    </div>
    
)
}
```

I have to display list of all comments (“children” field) for a given ID in the given API but I don't know how to access it. Comments are in a tree form.
I tried the above method but it didn't work.
id ex: https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/items/12701272

Comment: This endpoint `https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?tags=(story,poll)` doesn't have a key called children in the response .

Answer (score 0):

If comments are stored in children, you need a nested map function. It's a similar concept to what you're doing with each story - the map method over stories programmatically maps over each individual story. Now, what you want is each individual comment within each individual story. So, have another map function within the story map function similar to this:

```
stories.map((story) => {
    ...what you had before...
    children.map((comment) => { return <div>comment.text</div> }); 
});
```